# Azure data studio running in black screen

Tags: centos7

I've installed azure data studio v: 1.14.1 on cent os but when i run it i just have a black screen 
I've tried to removed it and install it again but the same problem still fallen

[image: This black screen i saw when i run it]

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue on Win 2012 R2 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only solution I have found that works in CentOS 7 is to download and install version 1.13.1 from this azure data studio [GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/releases/tag/1.13.1). I tried the other, newer versions, as well as using --disable-gpu as used for a similar issue in Windows [here](http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.com/2019/03/How-to-Fix-Azure-Data-Studio-Blank-Black-Screen.html) without success.

Comment: Unfortunately i have tried to disable hardware acceleration but also it's  useless ...

Comment: Thank you the old version is work correctly ... The Problem is in V: 1.14.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where is started with a blank screen or even red and white boxes. I was able to get it going by disabling gpu. Same with vscode as well..

azuredatastudio --disable-gpu
code --disable-gpu